# Canvas.drawImage not working

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage

I know this question has been asked lot of times, but i am not able to figure out what am i doing wrong

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

function handleFiles(files) {
  var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var imageType = /^image\//;

    if (!imageType.test(file.type)) {
      continue;
    }

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.classList.add("obj");
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    preview.appendChild(img); // Assuming that "preview" is the div output where the content will be displayed.

    img.onload = drawImage(img);

  }
}
var drawImage = function(img) {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

}
```

```html
<div id="preview"></div>
<input type="file" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: what is not working?i can see the image

Comment: That is `img` appended into `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gmcyhs6a/)

it should be

```
img.onload = function(){drawImage(img)};
```

if there is no method argument you can call

```
img.onload = drawImage;
```

instead of

```
 img.onload = drawImage()// not correct
```

syntax is

```
x.onload = funcRef;//reference
```

you should assign a function reference .if you assign `drawImage(img)` then return value of `drawImage(img)` will be assigned to onload function

Comment: can you add an explanation

Comment: makes sense. But i am still confused, why is return value so important in this case? The function still gets executed, then why does canvas not renders properly?

Comment: @a1626 because when function get executed img hasn't loaded

Comment: won't the function get executed at `onload`

Comment: @a1626 no .it only works if you give method reference correctly